# Using Microsoft Membership Class in a C++ Code

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net

We have a web application developed using the C# code. The required authentication of the user is done using System.Web.Security module i.e Membership Class("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librarY/System.Web.Security.Membership%28v=vs.90%29.aspx").

Now there is a new requirement to achieve the same (couple of web related functionality) using a C++ code. All the relevant functionality is ported to the C++ code, but stuck with the authentication of the user because of the usage of Membership Class in C#.

So, is there a way to authenticate the user (created using the Membership Class from the C# code) in the C++ code.?

Comment: You're discussing ASP.NET membership. What does that mean in C++ code? Presumably, your C++ code does not run inside ASP.NET. (If it does, you already are running mixed code. Keep your C# code in C# then)

Comment: Its not a Mixed Code. C# is an independent IIS and C++ is another independent Win32 exe. But both of them operate on the same database (In C++ I'm using ODBC middle-ware for accessing the DB Content). User creation is done through C#(i.e ISS) using Membership Classes (link is in question). But now i need to authenticate the same user in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The user database exists only in IIS, as far as we can tell, so your Win32 app has to check with IIS. Just build a small webservice in C# which you check from C++.

Comment: I built a C# interface class and created a dll out of it, and then linked the dll to the C++ code. Thanks for your input.